# Process WaitForExit()

Tags: c#

I use the below statements in my application:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = 'FileName';
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(900000); // 15 minutes
```

How does it work? After 15 minutes, if the 'FileName' is still running/executing, will `process.WaitForExit(900000);` kill the process? Else the execution goes to the next statement without killing the 'FileName', i.e. 'FileName' continue to run till it's execution completed?

Comment: There is no guarantee that WaitForExit(900000) is exactly 15 minutes that would be entirely up to Windows scheduler

Comment: @Ramhound, it appears you may be trying to indicate that if the process ended before the elapsed 15 minutes it would return right? But I mean, if you tell Windows to wait for 15 minutes and the process is still running are you implying Windows will just arbitrarily decide whether it wants to call you back or not? Maybe Windows will say, nah, I'm tired, give me 9 more minutes right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if a time-limited `WaitForExit` returns due to the limit being elapsed the process continues to run.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Process.CloseMainWindow();
```

this will close the main window of your application and therefore end it smoothly.