# Retry the File for three times If the File Exists through Recursive Method and which returns Boolean in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, recursion, c#-4.0

My Requirement is I Want My File to be Retried for 3 times If the Particular File Exists , I Have Achieved But the thing is I Want the Working Copy through Recursive Method which returns Boolean , Below Is my Working Code Which is not returned Boolean :

```
public void Process(int count = 0)
    {
        bool exists = File.Exists("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\RevisionNumber.txt");

        if (exists && count < 3)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\SvnUninstallation.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(2000); // or long enough to ensure the uninstall process finishes executing

            //File exists
            Console.WriteLine("File exists");

            Process(++count);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exceeded retry of 3 times. File did not uninstall.");
        }

        if (!exists)
            Console.WriteLine("File uninstalled");

    }
```

Could Any One Help Me Out by Providing the solution through recursive method which returns boolean , and retry the file for three times if the file exists if not exists then execute only once.

Comment: Recursion in an imperative language like C# is usualy a bad idea as it is likely to give you stack-overflows. try using a `for` instead.

Comment: Ok , But the requirement is Retry the File for three times If the File Exists if not exists then execute only once through Recursive Method which return boolean

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want? I do not understand the question? You just want to return true or false?

Comment: Why does it have to be recursive? And instead of using a static `Process.Start` and then "`Sleep` long enough so it finishes" you should use an instance and call [`WaitForExit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx). You can follow [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838121/process-waitforexit) where you set `Filename` to your SvnUninstallation.exe.

Comment: I need more information before I can help you. Why do you want recursive methods? Wy retry three times if file exists?

Comment: Maybe it has to be recursive because it is his homework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retry for three times If the File Exists in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552645/retry-for-three-times-if-the-file-exists-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Actually my TL Wants to be done through Recursive My Requirement is I Had an SVN Installed in my PC So i'm Uninstalling through automation process , so the thing is when the SVN is installed by default RevisionNumber.txt file is generated , So when run the SVN Uninstallation file through C# Code by mistake if the user presses cancel button then we don't know whether svn is uninstalled or not so i want the file to be appeared for three times

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552645/retry-for-three-times-if-the-file-exists-in-c-sharp/41553771?noredirect=1#comment70313605_41553771

Comment: So When i run the code it checks for the RevisionNumber.txt file if file exists then it will retry for 3 times . If not exists then not required to retry , Got the Solution but i want to return boolean and need to retry the process based on count

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
public bool Process(int count = 0)
{
    if (File.Exists("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\RevisionNumber.txt") && count < 3)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\SvnUninstallation.exe");
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // or long enough to ensure the uninstall process finishes executing

        //File exists
        Console.WriteLine("File exists");

        if(Process(++count))
           return true;
    }
    if (!File.Exists("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\RevisionNumber.txt"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File uninstalled");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exceeded retry of 3 times. File did not uninstall.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

But you should definitly await the Process you started before continuing (not only by gussing time but by Process.WaitForExit()).

Comment: How to Call this in the page load ??